# ReactJS - error passing an argument to a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've got the following Reactjs code. It generates an inline menu (list of elements). If I click on a particular element, I'd like it to be output in console but it does not work.

```
import React from "react";


export default class GalleryHeader extends React.Component {

  handleClick(cat) {
    console.log(cat);
  }
  createItems(items) {
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      output.push(<li onClick={this.handleClick({items[i]})}>{items[i]}</li>);
    return output;
  }
  render() {

    return (
     <ul class="list-inline">
      {this.createItems(this.props.menuItems)}
     </ul>

    );
  }
}
```

There seems to be an error in calling the function

```
{this.handleClick({items[i]})}
```

When I remove the function argument like below, it works fine:

```
handleClick() {
    console.log("test");
  }
createItems(items) {
   var output = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
     output.push(<li onClick={this.handleClick}>{items[i]}</li>);
```

Please advise.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a ReactJS error, it's a simple JS error.

You need to pass the function reference to the `onClick` event. When you do `<li onClick={this.handleClick({items[i]})}>{items[i]}</li>` you're executing that function and passing its result to the event.

The correct call would be something like

`<li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, items[i])}>{items[i]}</li>`

That way your `this` scope doesn't change and you can also receive params.

Another solution would be using ES6 arrow function as:

`<li onClick={() => this.handleClick(items[i])}>{items[i]}</li>`

What's the difference here?

Well, now you're passing a function reference (as `() => {}` implies) that will call your `this.handleClick()` afterwards.

> Tips not related to your question

Firstly, you should be using `className` instead of `class` when using JSX syntax. That's easy to forget!

Secondly, it's recommended to use a `key` attribute whenever you're rendering elements withing a loop. So your `<li>`s would be:

`<li key={i} onClick={() => this.handleClick(items[i])}>{items[i]}</li>`

This way React can optimize its rendering and stop giving you warning/errors on your browser console.

You can take further reading into keys in React docs:
[Fragment](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html), 
[Multiple Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) and 
[Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)

Comment: Bind can be expensive, an arrow function gets the same result: `onClick={ () => this.handleClick(items[i]) }`. [But both are discouraged for performance](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md)

Comment: Thank you  for additional info

Answer (score 1):

In your code there are several mistakes

1. You should pass to `onClick` reference to function, but you call it and result is passing to `onClick` - but result is `undefined`(`onClick={ undefined }`) that's why click does not work. To solve this problem you can use `.bind`

   ```
   onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this, items[i]) }
   ```

   or [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

   ```
   onClick={ () => this.handleClick(items[i]) }
   ```
2. In React to set class attribute you should use `className` attribute instead of `class`

   ```
   <ul className="list-inline">
   ```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/35232/)